# ES6: is there a way to monkey patch an exported class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-class, jupyter-lab

Is there a hack to override an exported class in a way that the changes is propagated to every module that imports it ? I'm trying to override a method that's exported from a library. The overriden changes are only persisted within the module which overrides it. Just looking out for any hacks to solve it ?

```
//Module A.js
import { ServerConnection } from '@jupyterlab/services';

ServerConnection.ContentsManager.overrideMethod = fnMyOverrideMethod;
//the above changes are only persisted with the module where it's overriden



 //Module B.js

 import { ServerConnection } from '@jupyterlab/services';

 //ServerConnection.ContentsManager.overrideMethod will not point to the fnMyOverrideMethod
```

Comment: Not trivially, because doing so would be horrible. Either use normal JS semantics (e.g., subclass etc) or composition. Spooky action at a distance leads to tears. Make it explicit.

Comment: Are `Module A` and `Module B` running in the same environment? Then it should work - there is only a single `ServerConnection`.

Comment: @Bergi: No, module A and Module B won't be in the same environment. Module B would be say part of the libray itself which would be importing ServerConnection.

Comment: @ikiw "part of a library" is not what I was asking about. Are they both loaded in the same js engine process? Or in general, what environment does the code run in - browser, node.js, something else?

Comment: yes, same js engine - Browser. But still it doesn't work! the override only lives in the module which overrides it and not to other modules that imports ServerConnection.